# Is there any way to convert AR8ISO8859P6 characterset data to AR8MSWIN1256 while querying?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

We have an application where we store customer information and entry made from the desktop application. We also store the Arabic names of the customers and it saves properly and is retrieved back properly.

Now, we have a requirement to query the data but the data is retrieved in junk characters.

On executing the following query, we get:

```
    SELECT *
  FROM v$nls_parameters
 WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'

NLS_CHARACTERSET = AR8ISO8859P6
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16
```

While querying the data from the table using the following query:

```
SELECT DUMP(LONG_NAME_ARAB,1016) FROM CIF WHERE CIF_NO=47;
```

We get the following data:

```
Typ=1 Len=24 CharacterSet=AR8ISO8859P6: bf,bf,bf,bf,bf,20,bf,bf,bf,bf,20,bf,bf,bf,bf,bf,20,bf,bf,bf,bf,bf,bf,bf
```

We tried converting the characterset to get the data in arabic using the following query:

```
SELECT   UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_RAW.CONVERT (
                                     UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw (cif.LONG_NAME_ARAB),
                                     'AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8ISO8859P6',
                                     'AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256'
                                  ))
 FROM   CIF WHERE CIF_NO=47
```

But unfortunately, it returns just junk characters. We tried using different approaches and characterset but it returns just junk characters.

Appreciated if someone can help us to get the data in Arabic because the application is displaying the data in Arabic and we do not have the source code to check how they are retrieving the data.

Comment: What do you get from `SELECT LONG_NAME_ARAB FROM CIF WHERE CIF_NO=47`?

Comment: What data do you expect that field to contain?  It seems unlikely that you intended to store 24 characters worth of data completely composed of 0xbf `؟` and 0x20 (space character).  You can look up the characters yourself (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-6).  It looks like whatever code is saving the data is the problem, not the code that is retrieving the data.

Comment: Your question is not clear when you say "*and is retrieved back properly*" and "*the data is retrieved in junk characters*" at the same time.

Comment: According result of `DUMP()`, your statement "*We also store the Arabic names of the customers and it saves properly and is retrieved back properly.*" cannot be true. How do you get proper result?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit we have an application in which the data is displayed properly. We have a problem retrieving the data in TOAD. We have checked the configuration of TOAD, everything is fine related to the fonts.

Comment: "*we have an application in which the data is displayed properly*" - that's not possible when `DUMP()` returns `CharacterSet=AR8ISO8859P6: bf,bf,bf,bf,bf,20,bf,bf,bf,bf,20,bf,bf,bf,bf,bf,20,bf,bf,bf,bf,bf,bf,bf` The **real** data is actually `؟ ؟ ؟ ؟ ؟  ؟ ؟ ؟ ؟  ؟ ؟ ؟ ؟ ؟  ؟ ؟ ؟ ؟ ؟ ؟ ؟`

Comment: I have used the following query to convert one field to different character sets but still, I don't get the result on the other hand, in the application, Arabic is properly displayed.     `SELECT
    qs.character_set AS target_charset,
    CONVERT(LONG_NAME_ARAB, qs.character_set, 'AL16UTF16') AS converted_data
FROM
    CIF 
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT VALUE AS character_set
    FROM V$NLS_VALID_VALUES
    WHERE PARAMETER = 'CHARACTERSET'
    ORDER BY VALUE) qs WHERE   CIF_NO = 47;
`